# Subjunctive use in that-clauses

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

Which is the better style of writing a "that-clause" using "insist"? Is option a the most accepted form of subjunctive usage?

a. He kept insisting that I not blame them.

b. He kept insisting that I must not blame them.

Comment: Sentence b., as you may know, does not reveal the subjunctive mood.

Comment: How about "He kept insisting that I do not blame them"? I think it will be also "He kept insisting that she do not blame them." No?

Comment: @karlalou No, in subjunctive, *do* is omitted.

Comment: Thank you. I found an example in Swan's PEU now!. :) That is: "We felt it desirable that he not leave school before eighteen." So, is the reason why the 'b' is better because 'a' sounds archaic or something?

Comment: I wanted to verify if the subjunctive format is correct in option a.

Comment: @karlalou It's a little bit old-fashioned, but I think it's not archaic. I don't know what construction the 'b' is, but in BrE, they usually use "should." Btw, Swan's book is my favorite too ^_^.

Comment: @skywardhope Yes, 'a' is a perfectly constructed subjunctive. 'b' is not, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically fine.  The **"must"** in B is superfluous and removes the subjunctive form; however, both are correct.  I would personally say and write letter A; however, I do not think that either one is wrong.

Somebody suggested inserting **"do"** and making what is called a periphrastic subjunctive such as in his example,

> "He kept insisting that she do not blame them."

Shakespeare used to use periphrastic subjunctives such as when he said,

> "If he do bleed..."

but the form is very uncommon in Modern English.  I would not use it, but I can't say it's completely wrong.